# Origin of AJAX request is DevTools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When I am debugging code I did not write in Chrome DevTools I look in the Network tab for XHR requests sent. Then I try to find where in the JS code the request is made.This is usually a pain and requires a lot of text searches to find where the request was made in the code. Is there a way jump to the line of code where the XHR request was made from the Network tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In developers console, under network tab you have initiator column. That should do the trick.